# android LinearLayout - ImageView gets pushed off the screen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I use the layout posted below to show messages by inflating that layout as a row into a ListView. The problem is that it works fine with a single-line message but when there are 2 lines or more the `ImageView` indicating the message state gets pushed off the screen, can't get the reason. Any ideas? Layout code and screenshot below.

[image]

That is the inflated layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimestamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="8sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_message_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTimestamp"
    android:background="@drawable/outgoing_bg"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessageOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMessageState"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if you try to delete the android:layout_gravity="bottom" and put the imageview below the textview?

Comment: I would have to change the layout orientation to vertical to do so. But I'd like the image on the bottom right of the textView, not below it

Comment: Ok, but try this once to see if the problem is comming from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimestamp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="10:20pm"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_message_holder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessageOutgoing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgMessageState"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="android developer tutorial in the world"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMessageState"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

change you linear layout width fill_parent

and add android:layout_weight="1" in textview

Comment: for me the solution was only the weight.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessageOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Medium Tesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeessssxt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

It gives the textview the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
          >

          <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMessageState"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Define your image view layout inside of Linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```